# Jquery - Bootstrap Thumbnail item view (google's)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popup, hover

Just to start - If you go to Google's homepage and have logged in with a gmail account, you will see an icon in the top right of 9 thumbnails. You hover over this and it displays a list of apps to select.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYhTU.jpg

Now to the question - How do I do something like this? I've found the image in bootstrap but haven't a clue in which direction to look for this.

I'm not asking for all the code to be posted here so I can copy paste and be done, I'm mainly asking for a point in the right direction to a topic/component which would cover this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start from [Button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns).

Then you would do a custom css for your `<li>` elements.
Which would have icons classes, and a special layout.

You may try something like this.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatemalimam/y9Tsd/)

Comment: Heya, I had a feeling they just used that with a custom border to see the little speech bubble like display. Trying with thumbnails inside the dropdown but currently it's looking very horrible o_o

Comment: I have updated the answer with somehow an example code I created.(jsfiddle link). @Gary You might start with ...

Comment: Heya, I found it! http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers . I've then done on-click it opens the popover just trying to find a way to add custom html into it!